# GCC compile and link raw output

Tags: gcc, assembly, mips

I am trying to get the raw instruction code output for a simple C program with function calls.

I have already searched on here and Google for the answer but can only find answers that are correct for single functions (no function calls).

A trivial example:

```
int main(){
    return addition(5, 7);
}

int addition(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

When I use `gcc -c test.c -o test.o` and then `objdump -d test.o` on this, the `JAL` (jump and link) instruction shows a jump to address `0x00000000` which is obviously incorrect, however when I compile the program fully, I get an enormous amount of junk in the `objdump` command

I am compiling with the mips compiler (and associated mips-objdump, etc).

The programs I am compiling are self contained (no external libraries, or system include files). What I want is a dump of the instructions where the `JAL` and equivalent instructions point to the correct addresses for the functions they call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your code is not linked, the addresses may or may not be resolved (absolute addresses certainly won't be). In the latter case, you should see relocation entries if you use `objdump -dr`. If you link your program, those issues should be gone, and if the program is really standalone (ie. not even C libraries) then all you see should be your code. You might want to use `-nostdlib` switch to gcc. I don't have mips gcc available, but here is the x86 version for illustration:

```
080480d8 <addition>:
 80480d8:       8b 44 24 08             mov    0x8(%esp),%eax
 80480dc:       03 44 24 04             add    0x4(%esp),%eax
 80480e0:       c3                      ret

080480e1 <main>:
 80480e1:       83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 80480e4:       c7 44 24 04 07 00 00    movl   $0x7,0x4(%esp)
 80480eb:       00
 80480ec:       c7 04 24 05 00 00 00    movl   $0x5,(%esp)
 80480f3:       e8 e0 ff ff ff          call   80480d8 <addition>
 80480f8:       83 c4 08                add    $0x8,%esp
 80480fb:       c3                      ret
```

That is all the code in the binary, and as you can see at `80480f3` the `call` is resolved. I expect it works similarly for mips.

Comment: Very interesting, and close to the result I want, adding the `-nostdlib` option worked (I'd love to know why), however my data starts at address `0x004000d0` (which corresponds to a warning message I got during compilation) however it is the `addition` function that starts at this address, not `main`. Is there a way of a) forcing main to this address or b) determining where `main` resides? I know that `crt0.o` and similar usually perform this task, however this is not an option for me

Comment: You can [force functions to be in particular sections](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-functions-in-arbitrary-sections-3119), then [force said sections to be at particular addresses](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-g_t_002d_002dsection_002dstart_003d_0040var_007bsectionname_007d_003d_0040var_007borg_007d-238).