# Unusual output from GCC/LD with custom __start

Tags: c, gcc, mips

As an extension of this question: [GCC compile and link raw output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469611/gcc-compile-and-link-raw-output)

I am trying to compile and link a piece of code with a custom `__start`. As a note, I do NOT require this to work on any known architecture, so compliance with any specification is not important, getting it to work consistently is.

I have a simple piece of assembly (which I got from a URL I can't find now).

```
.set noreorder  /* so we can use delay slots explicitly */

    .text
    .globl main
    .globl __start
    .type __start,@function
    .ent __start

__start:
    jal main;
    nop;
    li $0,1;
    .end __start
```

If I understand this correctly, all this does is call my main method, do a no-op in the branch-delay slot, then write the number 1 to register 0 (I know this violates the MIPS specification, it is intentional - it denotes completion of the code and is "caught" before it actually occurs).

However, when I use the mips `ld` to link this with an example piece of code using this command `mips-linux-gnu-ld --section-start=.text=0 start.o main.o -o executable`

I get some unusual output when viewed with `objdump`

```
00000000 <.pic.main>:
0:  3c190000    lui t9,0x0
4:  0800022b    j   8ac <main>
8:  273908ac    addiu   t9,t9,2220
c:  00000000    nop

00000010 <__start>:
10: 0c000000    jal 0 <.pic.main>
14: 00000000    nop
18: 24000001    li  zero,1
1c: 00000000    nop

.........

000008ac <main>
.........
```

No matter how trivial my test program, I always get the same `.pic.main` function. However, in some cases it appears above `__start` and in some cases below.

I would like to remove this "function" entirely, but failing that would like it to always appear AFTER the  `__start`.

As a bonus, if anyone knows what this function is or why it occurs, I'd be intrigued.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a position-independent jumping code. The linker doesn't know where your things are going to be put, so it creates a PIC for all cases. A relative jump, or a jump using a register could solve the problem, although it wouldn't be the *jump and link*.

I would try using

- `-mrelax-pic-calls` to turn PIC calls that are normally dispatched via register `$t9` into direct calls. This is only possible if the linker can resolve the destination at link-time and if the destination is within range for a direct call.
- `mbranch-cost=num` to set the cost of branches to roughly num “simple” instructions. "This cost is only a heuristic and is not guaranteed to produce consistent results across releases."
- `-mno-shared` for not to generate code that is fully position-independent, and that can therefore be linked into shared libraries
- `-mno-embedded-pic`

I'd put my money on one the first two.

Comment: according to : https://dmz-portal.mips.com/wiki/GCC_MIPS_Options_Support_Status, the GCC MIPS toolchain does not support -mrelax-pic-calls

Comment: "last modified on 14 April 2013". Well, if so, it's very unfortunate. On the other hand, you can still try to use the others.